# Powerapp with sharepointlist how to make more search with dropdrown and one more search textbox

Tags: powerapps, sharepoint-list

Hi i don't even know where to start becouse when i change the code it just make error

SortByColumns(Filter([@Möbler]; StartsWith(Rubrik; TextSearchBox1.Text)  ); "Title"; If(SortDescending1; SortOrder.Descending; SortOrder.Ascending))

I want to add a extra search box **(Sökobjekt2)**
I have one freetext/oneLine what have the name **Kategori** in the **@Möbler** SharepointList

And i want to be able to choose from a dropdown **(1,2,3)** but the values shall be connected to the Sharepintlists values (Example Vit(White),Svart(Black),Röd(Red)...)

I know how to get the value som a free text feald. But i want it to be connected to a choise List from a column
[image]
[image]